# How do you upload product photos to Amazon?

Tags: photos, amazon

I bought something from Amazon that came malfunctioning in certain areas. I would like to upload a photo depicting this malfunction to the product's page to warn other users of this problem. I read [Amazon's FAQ](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=14061811) about how to upload photos, but they seem to be outdated.

The FAQ states:

> To add product images to existing listings:
>
> Go to the product detail page of the item you want to add an image to.
>
> Click Share your own customer images from the main view, or Upload images when looking at existing customer images.

I did not see any of the aforementioned interface items on the product page.

Comment: Those are the instructions for a product vendor which it sounds like you are not in this case. You won't have that option for a product for which you are not the publisher/vendor/author.

Comment: @batpigandme I've seen regular people upload photos depicting defective parts on other products. It is labeled with the user's username, which is not the same as the product vendor. It is highly unlikely that a product vendor would knowingly harm his/her own company.

Comment: yeah, just the instructions to which you were referring were from the vendor page